# iOS7 UICollectionView how to move a single cell to a different section with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7, uicollectionview

I have an app with a list of articles that a user can read. Once the user taps an article, I want to present it to the user, and then animate moving the cell representing an article to a different collection view section, representing read articles:

```
Unread  | Read
0 0 0 0 | X X
```

The code below causes all cells to reload, which looks like all of them flashing with background color. **Is there a way for me to animate moving once cell from one section of a collection view to another?**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([collectionView isEqual:self.largeCollectionView])
    {
        //position the tapped image at the end and animate reload
        UIImage* image = largeImages[indexPath.row];
        [largeImages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [largeImages addObject:image];
    }


    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
         [collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}
```

Comment: Have you successfully found a way of moving the item to another section with animation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `-moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`? It sounds like that provides exactly what you are looking for.

You appear to be changing the data backing your collection view and then relying on `-reloadSections:` to update the UI. That unsurprisingly reloads every cell in the section. Since you know exactly what changes you have been performed you could at least use `-deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:` and `-insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` to indicate exactly where you removed and re-inserted this image.